# read std::deque from file easily

Tags: c++, io, iterator, ofstream, deque

I have a variable with type `std::deque<float>`, I'm sriting its contents to a file like following:

```
std::deque<float> queue;
// ...
std::ofstream file ("out.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    file.precision(12);
    std::copy(queue.begin(), queue.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(file, ";"));
}
file.close();
```

Is there a straightforward way to read it back from file like the way I wrote it? I mean without reading file and then looping?

Comment: See the reading in part of the selected answer to the duplicate. It applies to `std::deque` too.

Comment: @juanchopanza That pesky `;` makes it a little more non-conforming that the straight-up linked answer (nice answer, btw), which assumes whitespace separation to allow those istream iterators to function. Hopefully the OP figures that out.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good point. guneykayim, if the duplicate is not useful let me know and I can re-open this question.

Comment: Well, I don't have to separate with `;`. It is working for me.